# Troubleshooting SQL Server Strange Timeout

Tags: sql, sql-server, timeout

I have a fairly generic select query. When I select the top 1245 results of a particular result set, it runs in under a second, as expected. However, if I run it for 1246, it runs continuously as if on an infinite loop. I've checked the formatting of rows 1245 and 1246, the data for which appears completely fine. I can also run the same query on a separate group of users numbering over 2300, which again, runs almost instantly, which makes me think it's not in relation to memory issues.

As a quick example of the query formatting:

```
SELECT TOP 1246 a.id, 
(SELECT TOP 1 col_1 FROM table_1 t INNER JOIN table_2 c ON t.id=c.id WHERE t.id=a.id) AS [columnAlias]
FROM table_3 a
```

Open to any ideas on troubleshooting.

If I can provide anything else that might help, just ask.

Comment: Posting the query plan might provide some insight.
Also, using `TOP 1` with no `ORDER BY` doesn't make much sense. It's also typically a bad idea performance-wise to use correlated subqueries for columns. You should be able to perform all of that logic quite easily using ordinary `JOIN`s.

Comment: The problem with that approach is that if you fix this performance problem then refactor it, then SQL Server will likely choose a new query plan and now you've done a bunch of work to correct a performance problem for code that never actually gets used - because now you have new code.

Comment: Yeah, good point. I'll re-factor it just now and see if it impacts the previous issue. If it does I'll make a new question for it, as this one will no longer be relevant. Appreciate the input.

Answer (score 1):

The difference in performance is probably due to changes in the execution plan.  You might want to check that statistics are up-to-date.

Second, your query really makes no sense, because the subquery has no relationship to the outer query.  So, you might as well accept that you are going to get a single value and move it to the `from` clause:

```
SELECT TOP 1246 a.id, col_1 AS [columnAlias]
FROM table_3 a CROSS JOIN
     (SELECT TOP 1 col_1 FROM table_1 t INNER JOIN table_2 c ON t.id=c.id);
```

Finally, if you have some other intention with your query, you should ask another question.  If you revise your question, you may invalidate this answer which draws downvotes.

Comment: Thanks Gordon, I had tried checking the execution plan of both queries, but they were identical.
Edit: Also, in terms of the query, I'd attempted to tone down the structure as much as possible, but may have went overboard to the point of removing some relevant parts. I'll edit the original to add the extra where condition in the subquery.

Answer (score 0):

"Running continuously on an infinite loop" when you get to a specific record makes me suspicious that you are encountering a deadlocking situation. There isn't anything obvious in what you posted that would cause it, so I'd suspect there is a context where this is running, e.g. it's part of a several step transaction, that could be the cause.